# Permissions on a text box

Tags: 2007, custom-list

I have a custom list and I would like to apply permissions to a text box in the new item and edit form.

Is this possible, if so how do I go about it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Jemelia,

Its not possible to set permissions on a Column/Field in SharePoint, however with some customization you should be able to do that..

You will need to use either a Visual Web Part or InfoPath form and write your custom logic to check permissions..

Comment: Thanks, Do you know if jquery can be used?

Comment: You can do it client side, but that's not the same as permissions. Guess it depends on how secure this field is. You can check effective permission / SPGroup etc to the user, and set the field attribute to readonly based on the result. But since its done client side the client could undo it.